# Divide the count of two search texts

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

When I search "SearchText1" then lets say there are 20 records.

When I search "SearchText2" then there are 10 results

Then I need to display a single value "2" in the dashboard

How do I formulate the Splunk query?

I tried below query where the numerator count is evaluated correctly but something is wrong with the denominator count related part:

```
index=something "searchText1" 
| stats count as NumeratorCount 
| eval numerator=NumeratorCount
| append [ | search index=something "searchText2" 
  | stats count as DenominatorCount 
  | eval denominator=DenominatorCount ]
| eval result=round(if(denominator=0,0,numerator/denominator), 2)
| table result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the `table` command, you'll see the numerator and denominator are in separate results.  The means the `eval` command computing 'result' is dividing numerator by NULL and NULL by denominator.

The fix is to combine the two rows using `appendcols` as in this example.

```
index=_internal "service_health_monitor"  
| stats count as NumeratorCount 
| eval numerator=NumeratorCount
| appendcols [ | search index=_internal "service_health_metrics_monitor"
  | stats count as DenominatorCount 
  | eval denominator=DenominatorCount ]
| eval result=round(if(denominator=0,0,numerator/denominator), 2)
| table result
```